# Calling a known subclass function from superclass?

Tags: perl, class, oop, subclass, superclass

I don't know if this is possible, but I would like to call a known subclass function from Perl.  I need something "generic" to call something more specific.  My superclass is going to assume that all classes that subclass it have a known function defined.  I guess this is similar to Java "implements".

For example let's say I have the following code:

```
GenericStory.pm

package Story::GenericStory;

sub new{
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = {};

   bless $self, class;
   return $self;
}

sub tellStory {
   my $self;

   #do common things
   print "Once upon a time ". $self->specifics();
}
```

#### #

```
Story1.pm

package Story::Story1;
use base qw ( Story::GenericStory );

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);

   return $self;
}

sub specifics {
   my $self;
   print " there was a dragon\n";
}
```

#### #

```
Story2.pm

package Story::Story2;
use base qw ( Story::GenericStory );

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);

   return $self;
}

sub specifics {
   print " there was a house\n";
}
```

#

```
MAIN

my $story1 = Story::Story1->new();
my $story2 = Story::Story2->new();

#Once upon a time there was a dragon.
$story1->tellStory();


#Once upon a time there was a house.
$story2->tellStory();
```

EDIT:

The code works fine.  I simply forgot a "my $self = shift;" in tellStory();

Comment: `use warnings;` should've caught that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works fine as is (modulo trivial errors); you may want to add in the superclass:

```
sub specifics {
    require Carp;
    Carp::confess("subclass does not implement required interface");
}
```

or similar.

Comment: you also want to return the string in specifics, not print it.  if you print it, it prints before the "Once upon a time"

Answer (score 0):

What you want is very much like a *trait* (or in Perl: a *role*).

Traits are a relatively recent addition to object oriented systems. They are like interfaces in that they can require an inheriting class to implement certain methods, but they are like a abstract superclass in that they can provide certain methods themselves.

The Moose object system allows roles. A class can be declared `with` a certain role. Here your example written with `MooseX::Declare`:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

role Story::StoryTeller{
    requires 'specifics';

    method tellStory() {
        print "Once upon a time ";
        $self->specifics();
    }
}

class Story::Story1 with Story::StoryTeller {
    method specifics() {
        print " there was a dragon\n";
    }
}

class Story::Story2 with Story::StoryTeller {
    method specifics() {
        print " there was a house\n";
    }
}

my $story1 = Story::Story1->new();
my $story2 = Story::Story2->new();

#Once upon a time there was a dragon.
$story1->tellStory();
#Once upon a time there was a house.
$story2->tellStory();
```

This isn't inheritance: `$story1->isa("Story::StoryTeller")` is false, but it *does* this role: `$story1->DOES("Story::StoryTeller")` is true.

For every class that `DOES` a certain role, an instance of that class `can` all methods of the role. Therefore, `$story1->can("tellStory")` is true, and in reverse for every `Story::StoryTeller` instance, `$instance->can("specifics")` will be true.

A role cannot be instantiated on its own.